# Memory leaks when Retrieving photos from Photo Library in ios

Tags: ios, memory, uiimage, memory-leaks, alasset

In my app, I want to Retrieve Photos and Videos from the Photo Library, and then save them into my app documents directory.
    Following is my codes:

```
- (UIImage *)getImageFromAsset:(ALAsset *)asset type:(NSInteger)nType
{

    ALAssetRepresentation *assetRepresentation = [asset defaultRepresentation];
    CGImageRef imageReference = [assetRepresentation fullResolutionImage];
    CGFloat imageScale = [assetRepresentation scale];
    UIImageOrientation imageOrientation = (UIImageOrientation)[assetRepresentation orientation];

    UIImage *iImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imageReference scale:imageScale orientation:imageOrientation];

    return iImage;
}

- (UIImage *)getImageAtIndex:(NSInteger)nIndex type:(NSInteger)nType
{
    return [self getImageFromAsset:(ALAsset *)_assetPhotos[nIndex] type:nType];
}

......

for (NSIndexPath *index in _dSelected) {
    DLog(@"the selected index is %@", index);
    image = nil;
    image = [ASSETHELPER getImageAtIndex:index.row type:ASSET_PHOTO_FULL_RESOLUTION];

    NSString *name = [ASSETHELPER getImageNameAtIndex:index.row];
    NSString *filepath = [files stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];
    NSString *aliapath = [alias stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];
    aliapath = [aliapath stringByAppendingString:THUMBNAIL];
    DLog(@"the files is %@ the alias is %@", filepath, aliapath);

    image = nil;
}

 If I retrieve just 20 or 30 photos, it would be ok, but if I retrieve too many photos(maybe 50 ones), the App will Terminate due to Memory Pressure. I think I have set the image to nil after every one image , so the ios system shoud get back the memory after each for loop. But why Memory leak happens?
```

Answer (score 0):

ARC still needs to manage your memory.  As long as you are in your for loop, ARC will never have the chnace to release your memory.  You need to put the inside of your loop within an autorelase pool.

```
for (NSIndexPath *index in _dSelected) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        DLog(@"the selected index is %@", index);
        image = nil;
        image = [ASSETHELPER getImageAtIndex:index.row type:ASSET_PHOTO_FULL_RESOLUTION];

        NSString *name = [ASSETHELPER getImageNameAtIndex:index.row];
        NSString *filepath = [files stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];
        NSString *aliapath = [alias stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];
        aliapath = [aliapath stringByAppendingString:THUMBNAIL];
        DLog(@"the files is %@ the alias is %@", filepath, aliapath);

        image = nil;
    }
}
```

This will let your memory get freed as you deal with each image.

Comment: Hi HalR，
    Thank you very very much! That is exactly what the problem is! After adding the autorelease pool, memory leak no long occurs. I think I have to read some books about memory controller. Thanks again.